# no such file or directory error in comparing two files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm very new in bash script and I wrote a code to compare an entered file with the files in a directory named new2 but i get the following error:

> line 8: [~/new1/file1: No such file or directory

here is my code:

```
input=0
while true; do
        echo "enter a file name from directory new1 to copy it to directory new2 "
        echo "or enter ctrl+c to exit: "
        read input
        i=0
        for F in $(ls ~/new2/) ;do
                if ["~/new1/$input" -ef $F] ;then
                        i=1
                        break
                fi
        done
        if [ $i -eq 0 ];then
                mv ~/new1/$input ~/new2/ 
                echo $input "moved succussfully"
        else
                echo "file exist"
        fi
done
```

can any one help me to fix this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Always use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting a question about shell script code you're having an issue with.

Comment: this site is so helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ["~/new1/$input" -ef $F] ;then`

You need a space before and after both brackets

`if [ "~/new1/$input" -ef $F ] ;then`